# MVC3 application with SubSonic entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orm, subsonic

I'm starting to write an MVC3 application that performs a basic search.  I've created a WCF service with a GetDataAsDataSet() method exposed and consume the service in my MVC project.  For now this method I think is the simplest, as it merely returns a data set.  I do want to add GetDataAsEntity() which returns the actual database entity type generated through SubSonic later (or now?)...

So far, I know that I need to have these entities in the Models folder of my MVC3 project if my service is returning a type of these entities.  However do these all need to end with "Models"?

SubSonic also creates [entityname]Controller.cs files - can these be placed in the controllers folders and rename the actual entity classes to [entityname]Models.cs ?

I'm thinking I need these in my Models folder, as I want to make use of the WCF Service, which I will ultimately have returning an entity entity type.

I can easily get the first solution to work (returning a simple datatable), it's the second option, that I need some assistance with - passing back the complex type from the WCF Service and consuming that in my MVC3 application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to customize your SubSonic T4 files and make all the generated classes have the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, then WCF should be able to directly serialize the records read from SubSonic.

Comment: The SubSonic classes are already decorated with [Serializable].  As I understand it, will automatically map all the fields.